# How to understand this definition of equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I often see this type of definitions of equivalence:

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on $\mathbb R$. We can define an equivalence relation on such functions by letting $f(x) \sim g(x)$ if $f'(x) = g'(x)$.

So the equivalence relation is $\sim = \lbrace (h(x), h(x)) \in S^2; h'(x) = h'(x) \rbrace$ where $S = \lbrace f(x) \rbrace $ for all $f$ that are differentiable on $\Bbb R$?

Comment: It's kind of saying $f$ and $g$ are different by a constant $c$?

Comment: @MonkeyKing Yeah, but the point of the example was to demonstrate the equivalence relation.

Comment: @SalmonKiller So, are you asking for a proof that this is an equivalence relation or if the description you gave is the right one... ?

Comment: @SolidSnake I have the proof that this is an equivalence relation. I was just confused about what this relation $\sim$ is, and it looks like your answer cleared that up for me.

Comment: @SalmonKiller I've made an edit to help you understand the general idea. Let me now if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly, but you're close. The relation is $\sim = \lbrace (g(x), h(x)) \in S^2; g'(x) = h'(x) \rbrace$.

It's very common to define relations in a set $X$ as

$$a \sim b \ \ \text{iff some property $P(a,b)$ involving $a$ and $b$ holds true}$$

In such a case, the relation that arises is

$$\sim= \{(a,b)\in X^2: P(a,b)\}.$$

(just to improve your mathematical notation, don't write "$S = \lbrace f(x) \rbrace $ for all $f$ that are differentiable on $\Bbb R$" but $S = \{ f(x) : \text{$f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R$}\} $).